# Can I use free() formally in VS2013?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TSIZE 45
struct film{
    char title[TSIZE];
    int rating;
    struct film *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct film *head = NULL;
    struct film *prev, *current;
    char input[TSIZE];

    puts("Enter first movie title:");
    while (gets(input) != NULL && input[0] != '\0')
    {
        current = (struct film*)malloc(sizeof(struct film));
        if (head == NULL)
            head = current;
        else
            prev->next = current;
        current->next = NULL;
        strcpy(current->title, input);
        puts("Enter your rating (0 - 10):");
        scanf("%d", &current->rating);
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            continue;
        puts("Enter next movie title(empty line to stop):");
        prev = current;

    }

    if (head == NULL)
        printf("No data entered.");
    else
        printf("Here is the movie list:\n");
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Movie: %s Rating: %d\n", current->title, current->rating);
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        free(current);
        printf("hehe.\n");
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Bye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Why can't this code be used formally in VS 2013? Is it just because of the use of the `free()` function that the code above can't work?
Perhaps `free()` can't work formally in VS2013???**

Sorry for posting the whole code, but system said that I can't submit this question due to lack of details....

Comment: whats the exact error the compier is throwing?

Comment: `free(current);...current->next;` you can't use `current` after `free`'d

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the pointer `current` after `free`ing it, which is *undefined behaviour*. Change

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    free(current);
    printf("hehe.\n");
    current = current->next;
}
```

to

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    struct film *tmp = current;
    printf("hehe.\n");
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

Note that you shouldn't use `gets` at all as it has been removed from the recent C standard C11 and notoriously bad for it's buffer overrun problems. Use [fgets()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) instead.

Also, don't cast the result of [malloc family functions](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).